# How should I initiate communication with a prospective employer/interviewer?

Tags: communication, careers

I met an employee from a company who's placements I will sit for in the next year. He, along with 2 of his colleagues had come to university to monitor that company's student program of which me and 4 others are a part of. I had some talk with him, mainly about the future agenda for the program and a little small talk.

I am of the opinion that making further communication with him will be helpful at the time of my placements. My motivation for this is that they may *influence* my future interviewers (remotely).

How do I initiate communication? I only have his email address.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? It is not clear what your question is about. You have a means to contact the person - what else do you need to know?

Comment: Erm, how must I exactly word it? I don't want to leave a wrong impression or notion but at the same time, I want to word in my usefulness. I can't speak right off the bat about placements etc. Some pointers or tips would be useful!

Comment: Well, you have met the person and you know how formal or informal you may want to be.

Comment: Also, what's the motivation for communicating with this person? What's in it for you and what's in it for them?

Comment: Motivation - They may _influence_ my future interviewers (remotely). Isn't that a possibility?

Comment: They may - which might work against you or for you.

Comment: Before you contact someone you need to have something to talk about.  "Hi, we met last week (end of message)" is not useful to anyone; in fact, it's likely to hurt you (he might flip the bozo bit on you).  Can you add to the question what you want to say to him?

Comment: @MonicaCellio "flip the bozo bit".  Very nice, i'm using that from now on.  And to the OP, you should basically just mention that you spoke with them the earlier week, and was interested in continuing that discussion.  give them your number, but mention that email would work just as well.  and make sure to THANK THEM at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While they may influence how you handle future interviews, I'm not sure I'd see that as enough motivation for them to stay in contact with you.  In wanting to build this relationship, what are you giving to them other than some of your time?  Consider what are you offering, what do they want, and how well can you match these as while I can understand how such a relationship benefits you, how does it benefit them?  That's the part I don't see at the moment and is the part that you have to resolve as that is the heart of your message in communicating them.  For example, you could send an e-mail like:

> Hi,
>
> I'd like to discuss your current challenges and how I may offer some
>   help in overcoming those challenges.  Could we meet for lunch sometime
>   this week to discuss this in more detail?  Thanks for listening to me.

Short and simple as what you want to have is a regular conversation that enables you to get a view of their operations and how you could fit in there.  At the same time, by offering some assistance to their problems, you could work your way into having an offer when the school year is over as if you can prove useful on this part-time basis, imagine what you could do in a permanent role.

Answer (score 3):

This is what [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/) is for. This is counting on the fact that the chap (and yourself) has a LinkedIn account.

> Hi [Insert Name],
>
> > It was great speaking with you at [insert convention here]. [Give some small talk on the changes/dynamics or new stuff about what you discussed]. I'm actually quite interested in joining the team @ [your company]. [Give short reason why]. If it's okay with you, I'd like to add you to my professional network on LinkedIn.